# QRCode scanning many values in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a QR scanner using iOS framework. After I scan the value of the QR I have an alert view which performs a segue.

Issue: when I try to scan, sometimes the values get scanned 3-4 times resulting in 4 alert views and 4 segues to the same page. How to rectify this?

Aim: I want to scan the value one time and perform segue to a new controller.

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {
        AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {
            [_statuslbl performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObj stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];

            self.tablenum=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[metadataObj stringValue]];
            NSLog(@"tablenum-----%@",self.tablenum);
           // NSString *ChkStr = [self.tablenum substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9,7)];
           // NSLog(@"check str:%@",ChkStr);

            _tablevalue=self.tablenum;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:_tablevalue forKey:@"qrcode"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIAlertController *alertController=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Qr Value Acquired!!" message:@"Your QR code has been scanned successfully!!." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                             handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {
                                           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.tablenum forKey:@"qrcode1"];
                                           [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                           AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
                                           [captureSession stopRunning];
                                           captureSession = nil;

                                         //  [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

                                           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"qrback" sender:self];

                                       }];
            [alertController addAction:okAction];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            });
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            [_scanqrb performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setTitle:) withObject:@"Start!" waitUntilDone:NO];
            _isReading = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try call `[captureSession stopRunning];` right after you got the value from your camera, that mean the first line in your delegate function above. If its not QR type, resume capturing by `[captureSession startRunning];`

Comment: can we take bool value and check that ? if one time segue done than bool value changed so next time segue not done.

Comment: @Tj3n I did that but still the same problem.

Comment: Make sure you stop the correct `captureSession`. Use bool is also another way to make it stop jump to your segue